# Canvas lines getting clipped in windows phone app

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm having a problem with content getting clipped on the canvas of a windows phone app. Here's the XAML for a page that reproduces the problem:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <ScrollViewer  x:Name="ChartScroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   >
            <Canvas x:Name="chartCanvas" Width="4000" Height="1000"   >
                <Line Stroke="Red" X1="0" X2="3000" Y1="100" Y2="100" />
                <Line Stroke="Yellow" X1="0" X2="3500" Y1="200" Y2="200" />
                <Line Stroke="Blue" X1="0" X2="4000" Y1="300" Y2="300" />
                <Line Stroke="Green" X1="2800" X2="2800" Y1="0" Y2="1000" />
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and here's a screen shot of the result:

[image]

The problem is that the red, yellow and blue lines seem to be getting clipped - I would expect them to go further than the green line horizontally and their lengths should be different as well. I can't work out why this is happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Trade your lines for <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="Red"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello @rip i have checked your problem and what i find is that you have done fine , actually there is problem with **line class** of **windows phone** you cannot make a line of length more than 2700 i have checked it out on device too. 
so what you can do is draw one more one from where the first line ended..just a workaround.I have checked it for Windows 8 , Wpf every thing just working fine.